# php document is uploaded out side of www folder how to make a downloadable link

Tags: php, html

directory of application server --

```
/var/www/html/testweb/index.php
c:/wamp/www/testweb/index.php
```

document has uploaded to

```
/var/documents/file1.pdf
c://documents/file1.pdf
```

now the document are out of the www root directory how i can link them for example if document is in:

```
/var/www/hmtl/testweb/document1/file1.pdf
c://wamp/www/testweb/document1/file1.pdf
```

it's easy to add a href link like

```
<a href="document1/file1.pdf>download</a>
```

How to add link to download if it's out of the www root directory

regards

Comment: Symbolic link to a folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make your file readable for php runner (for example www-data for apache in ubuntu). Then link to a php file with:

```
<a href='http://yourhost/path/to/downloader.php'>Download file</a>
```

And edit `downloader.php` to make your file downloadable:

```
    $filename = 'path/to/your/file';
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));
    die($content);
```

Replace  `$filename='path/to/your/file'` with `$filename='c://documents/file1.pdf'`

Comment: the question is file.pdf which is to be download it's out of the wwwroot folder means it's out of web directory

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you make your file and folder readable for www-data, it will work.

Comment: so $filename = 'c://DOC/'; this is the folder how to do it where the index is on "c://wamp/www/testweb/index.php"

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not sure about windows platforms but I think it will work.

Comment: here i tested on linux too no result for me, but the idea is document is out of the wwwroot just want to download it.

Comment: I know that you want to download a file out of www directory. for example if you put your file in '/home/file.pdf' and change filename to this pat, I think it should work. can you update your answer and add your current exactly paths and your php file?

Comment: thanks it's worked here, i am working with php have document uploaded with a secure page like user and password authentication and each user are alow to see it's uploaded document now how can i make those document secure and only let the specific user see as you know if some one know the file name and path with out authentication will be able to download.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following the question. Do you want to keep your folder safe? In my answer it doesn't show your real file path to visitors. it just shows this path `http://yourhost/path/to/downloader.php`. If you have a another question, I think that's a good idea to post another question and explain well.

Comment: it's out of the question, if we could chat...!

Comment: You can use my email. see my website that's in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming safe mode is off and moving it is not an option, you could use `file_get_contents()` to retrieve the file data, `.htaccess` to change the URL to .pdf and then `header()` to set the correct header for the file. Basically, make a new PHP script that returns the file with the correct headers and then use `.htaccess` to make your browser think it's a legit PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple, You can just add more directories into the httpd.conf or you can set up virtual hosts.

### Add Directories

left click wamp>apache> htttp.conf

at the very end add
Alias /WEBSITENAME "X:/PATH/TO/FILES/"

```
<Directory "X:/PATH/TO/FILES/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
             Allow from all
</Directory>
```

> > http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,72262,76713

---

Set the access only for the localhost

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: here i dont want to host this directory, but i want this directory to only be usable by the hosted files on hosted directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about specifying the full path.

```
<a href="file://c://wamp/www/testweb/document1/file1.pdf>download</a>
```

Hope this helps you